# VSTS No test is available

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working with Visual Studio Team Services for the first time, and am setting up a simple scenario of a C# class library with a MSTest project. I want to setup automated builds, which also executes the tests. However this is not working. I've searched about it a lot, and most issues seems to be related to different test adapters like NUnit. This is not the case here, since I'm just using the default testing framework.

Can anyone help me and let me know what step I'm missing or doing wrong?

The only message is "Warning: No test is available in ..." with a lot of referenced dll's.

---

This is the complete log:

2017-11-20T08:43:16.5294822Z ##[section]Starting: VsTest - testAssemblies
2017-11-20T08:43:16.5294822Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-20T08:43:16.5294822Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2017-11-20T08:43:16.5294822Z Description  : Run tests with Visual Studio test runner
2017-11-20T08:43:16.5294822Z Version      : 2.2.3
2017-11-20T08:43:16.5294822Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-20T08:43:16.5294822Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
2017-11-20T08:43:16.5294822Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5500059Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5500059Z ========================================================
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5520059Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5520059Z Test assemblies : **\*test*.dll,!**\obj\**
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5520059Z Test filter criteria : null
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5530063Z Search folder : d:\a\1\s
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5540068Z Run settings file : d:\a\1\s
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5540068Z Run in parallel : false
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5540068Z Run in isolation : false
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5592822Z Path to custom adapters : d:\a\1\s
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5592822Z Other console options : null
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5600072Z Code coverage enabled : false
2017-11-20T08:43:17.5610070Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2017-11-20T08:43:17.9153146Z ========================================================
2017-11-20T08:43:18.1313359Z [command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" @d:\a_temp\dafe1090-cdce-11e7-9191-978614a9beba.txt
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3163422Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.26929.2
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3163422Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z 
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z vstest.console.exe 
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\CommonTestDotNetCore\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Common_Core.test.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\CommonTestDotNetCore\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\CommonTestDotNetCore\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\CommonTestDotNetCore\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\LibraryTests.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3173423Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3183421Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3193424Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3193424Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3193424Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3193424Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3193424Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3203422Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z "d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z /logger:"trx"
2017-11-20T08:43:18.3213426Z /TestAdapterPath:"d:\a\1\s"
2017-11-20T08:43:19.0238269Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2017-11-20T08:43:22.1177350Z **Warning: No test is available in** d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\CommonTestDotNetCore\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Common_Core.test.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\CommonTestDotNetCore\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll d:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\CommonTestDotNetCore\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll d:\a\1\s\ConsoleApp1\CommonTestDotNetCore\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.18\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll d:\a\1\s\TestSolution\LibraryTests\bin\Release\LibraryTests.dll. **Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.**
2017-11-20T08:43:22.1237346Z 
2017-11-20T08:43:22.1237346Z 
2017-11-20T08:43:22.2437321Z Information: Additionally, you can try specifying '/UseVsixExtensions' command if the test discoverer & executor is installed on the machine as vsix extensions and your installation supports vsix extensions. Example: vstest.console.exe myTests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true
2017-11-20T08:43:22.2437321Z 
2017-11-20T08:43:28.4823923Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.
2017-11-20T08:43:28.4863923Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testAssemblies

---

EDIT: dotnet test results:

These are the results of the dotnet test:

2017-11-23T09:16:25.4507466Z ##[section]Starting: dotnet test
2017-11-23T09:16:25.4517463Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-23T09:16:25.4517463Z Task         : .NET Core
2017-11-23T09:16:25.4517463Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command. For package commands, supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
2017-11-23T09:16:25.4517463Z Version      : 2.1.8
2017-11-23T09:16:25.4517463Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-23T09:16:25.4517463Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2017-11-23T09:16:25.4517463Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-23T09:16:26.4307767Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test --configuration release --logger trx --results-directory d:\a_temp
2017-11-23T09:16:35.5529647Z MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
2017-11-23T09:16:35.5799660Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-11-23T09:16:35.5849659Z ##[warning]No test result files were found.
2017-11-23T09:16:35.5879662Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : 
2017-11-23T09:16:35.5979646Z ##[section]Finishing: dotnet test

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Comment: I have the same issue and not yet resolved using the solutions as suggested in this thread. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a .Net Core test, so you can run tests through **.Net Core** task (Version: `2.*`; Command: `test`; Arguments: `--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)`; Check **Publish test results** option).

If you are using `1.*` version of **.Net Core** task:

1. Specify this Arguments: `--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --logger "trx"`
2. Add **Publish Test Results** task (Test result format: `VSTest`; Test results files: `**\*.trx`; Search folder: **$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)**)

You also can do it through Visual Studio Test task:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work... Added the results of the dotnet test in my question (too long for the comment section)

Comment: By the way, I have two test projects in this build, one .NET Core 2.0, and one "normal" .NET Framework test project (I want to be able to use both options). 
Both test projects doesn't work...

Comment: Using the second option, I get at least some test results from my .NET Core test project! Awesome! 
It still fails the build though (while the tests are all passed)... I will look into this and get back to you.

Do you have an advice how to get the "standard" .NET unit tests working?

Comment: This is the test result for .NET Core tests: 

2017-11-23T09:40:42.3174780Z Test Run Failed.
2017-11-23T09:40:42.3194767Z Test execution time: 12.3926 Seconds
2017-11-23T09:40:42.3554763Z Results File: d:\a\1\s\TestResults\buildguest_factoryvm-az248_2017-11-23_09_40_41.trx
2017-11-23T09:40:46.9246800Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2017-11-23T09:40:46.9246800Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\...\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-11-23T09:40:48.1249967Z ##[error]VsTest task failed.

Comment: Regarding Dotnet test task, you need to specify the core project (e.g. **/*coretest*.csproj). Regarding multiple type of test projects, you may add additional visual studio test task to run them separately, cannot find the way to run them together. Regarding the .Net Core Tests fail issue, I'd suggest asking separate questions in new forum threads. Thus, forum readers may recognize questions and answers easily. You need to provide the detail log (set system.debug variable to true, then queue build) in the new thread.

Comment: Hi Starian,

The dotnet core test project is working great now! Thanks for your advice. If I need more help on the other tests, I will make a new thread indeed.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming here from a web search, I was getting the same error message, but not in VSTS or using .NET Core. The issue was I had a mismatch between the "Platform Target" of my test project and the project-under-test. This can be modified under:

> Project Properties -> General -> Platform Target

This modifies the  node in the MSBuild file/project file, for the given build configuration (Debug/Release/etc.).