# Azure VSTS not running mixture of frameworks NET48 and NETCoreApp3.1

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have out Azure pipeline setup to run our unit tests, using the VSTest task:

```yaml
  - task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
      inputs:
        packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
        versionSelector: 'specificVersion'
        testPlatformVersion: '17.6.3'

    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
      inputs:
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\*FunctionalTests.dll
          **\*UnitTests.dll
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
          !**\obj\**
        searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
        codeCoverageEnabled: true
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        diagnosticsEnabled: true
```

Our project has a mixture of unit tests some that have the target framework of `net48` only and other that have `net48;netcoreapp3.1`. We recently noticed a load of our unit tests aren't running and pinned it down to the tests that just target `net48` are not running.

I read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47407139/1266043)) that a mixture of frameworks won't run correctly so splitting them into seperate tasks would be a good way to go about it.

Anybody have any clue how todo that? My DevOps skills are lacking. I tried setting the Framework via the `otherConsoleOptions: '/Framework:net48'` but this didn't work for me.

---

**Update 1**

So have managed to try out some of the advice. Currently modified our current pipeline to specify the .NET48 framework and run that only.
So in the YAML I added `otherConsoleOptions: '/Framework:.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'` to the VSTest@2 task

This didn't work for me had a few warnings in the log, a handful like:
`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Could not find or load a type. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131522)`

and others similiar to:

`MSTestAdapter failed to discover tests in class 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute' of assembly 'D:\a\1\s\Tests\bin\Debug\net48\Tests.dll'. Reason Configuration system failed to initialize.`

---

**Update 2**

Made some more progress with this. Stumbled across LINK which hinted at an issue with the mixing of unit tests that target netcoreapp3.1/net48 AND test projects targeting solely net48. By adding a `pathToCustomAdapter`and pointing it to a location that contains `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll` (and its related DLLs).

Made the necessary changes in the below YAML

```yaml
    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'VS Tests
      inputs:
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\*UnitTests*.dll
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
          !**\obj\** 
        vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
        pathtoCustomTestAdapters: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\TestTools'
```

This has worked however I am still getting `Failed to discover tests from assembly D:\a\1\s\TESTS\bin\Debug\net48\UnitTests.dll. Reason:Configuration system failed to initialize` for a handful of test projects. I will continue to expirment and update when I can.

---

**Update 3 - The Fix**

Finally got to the bottom of the issue and managed to fix it so that now ALL Unit Tests using both frameworks are running. These are the changes I made (for anyone who has this issue in the future).

- Add `pathtoCustomTestAdapters: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\TestTools'` to the `VSTest@2` task.
- Add a `TestTools` folder to my project root (this isn't essential you can easily just reference the location of the Microsoft TestPlatform DLLs like a UnitTest projects bin folder. I did this to be very specific and obvious what is entailed in the fix and of course if that project ever dissapears or is renamed the running of the tests will fail.
- Add the following DLLs to the `TestTools` folder (these are the DLL's that come from the 3 main MS Test Nuget packages):

  - Microsoft.TestPlatform.AdapterUtilities.dll
  - Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll
  - Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll
  - Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll
  - Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll

Comment: Hi there, May I know if the test assemblies `*FunctionalTests.dll` and `*UnitTests.dll` are generated under different paths based on their frameworks? If yes, you may consider searching and running the tests from different `searchFolder` in separate `VSTest` tasks.

Comment: Hi there, How is the test going from your side? May I ask if the suggestion below can help resolve this issue? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to set the **/Framework:** argument in VSTest Task to specify the framework version.

You can use the following format: `otherConsoleOptions: '/Framework:.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'`

For example:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*FunctionalTests.dll
      **\*UnitTests.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    otherConsoleOptions: '/Framework:.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'
    diagnosticsEnabled: true
```

To set the .netcore version, you can use the format: `otherConsoleOptions: '/Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'`

Here is the result:

[image]

On the other hand, the VS task will support using mixture of frameworks when using the VS test tool version higher than 17.3.

Refer to this doc: [Does the VSTest task support running tests that target multiple target frameworks at a time?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#does-the-vstest-task-support-running-tests-that-target-multiple-target-frameworks-at-a-time)

> Yes, starting from version 17.3 VSTest does support running tests that target multiple target frameworks at a time. Prior to that, this wasn't possible due to a limitation from the VSTest platform side.

> If you want to run tests that belong to multiple target frameworks, you'll need to install a compatible version of VSTest via Visual Studio Test Platform Installer and set vsTestVersion to toolsInstaller to use it.

Test to install the VStest tool version 17.6.3 as yours, it can work as expected.

Framework settings in repo:

[image]

Here is my yaml sample:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 3.1.x'
  inputs:
    version: 3.1.x

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Visual Studio Test Platform Installer'
  inputs:
    versionSelector: specificVersion
    testPlatformVersion: 17.6.3

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*test*.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\** 
    vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is amazingly helpful. I will apply some of these changes to the pipeline and see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: @ree6 Glad to know the answer can give you some help. You can do more test. If the answer can help you solve the issue, you may consider accepting it.

Comment: Yeah will do. I'm struggling to integrate it at the moment and get to the unit test tasks but will carry on and see how I get on.

Comment: Just tried some of your advice out - see update above.

Comment: Just realised something worth mentioning, we have a variety of different test projects:
some are targetting `<TargetFrameworks>net48;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>` - these ones seem to run, whil others are targeting just `   <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>` and these ones are not running

Comment: You can try to put these two projects into two VSTest tasks respectively for testing, and then check the results

Comment: On the other hand, you can add the argument: `--framework net48` to the build step and check if the warning will disappear

Comment: Thank you will try both of those out today. Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256117/discussion-between-ree6-and-kevin-lu-msft).

Comment: I am marking this as the answer as eventually lead to the right steps needed to fix my issue - I have detailed the actual fix in my post under Update 3